# Convert AUMID to Application Name C#

Tags: c#, windows

Given AppUserModelID (AUMID) 
Is there a way to get the application name from this data (without attempting to do some string manipulation on the AppUserModelID)?

I am looking for an api call to handle this or something of that nature.

In the case below the application name would be "Microsoft Edge"

```
 <start:Tile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="2" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge" />
```

How can I alter the following code to accept an AUMID instead of an appname.

```
function Pin-App {    param(
        [string]$appname,
        [switch]$unpin
    )
    try{
        if ($unpin.IsPresent){
            ((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | ?{$_.Name -eq $appname}).Verbs() | ?{$_.Name.replace('&','') -match 'Unpin from Start'} | %{$_.DoIt()}
            return "App '$appname' unpinned from Start"
        }else{
            ((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | ?{$_.Name -eq $appname}).Verbs() | ?{$_.Name.replace('&','') -match 'Pin to Start'} | %{$_.DoIt()}
            return "App '$appname' pinned to Start"
        }
    }catch{
        Write-Error "Error Pinning/Unpinning App! (App-Name correct?)"
    }
}
```

this powershell function will work by providing "Microsoft Edge" as the appname.

Comment: What do you mean by "application name"?

Comment: @conio application name of Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge in the xml would be "Microsoft Edge" . I am using this name to pin to the start menu

Comment: @conio Are you making riddles? Im curious why this basic question does not make sense to you? Maybe there is where the answer lies

Comment: No. I'm asking what an "application name" *is*. I never heard of such a thing, in the sense of a well-defined technical term, and I doubt it exists. Lets say I set the AUMID on an LNK file pointing at... say `C:\Windows\system.ini` to be *`abcd`*. What kind of "application name" to you expect to get from this AUMID?

Comment: @conio I updated the context of "application name" to help understand the question I am asking. Does the update make more sense to you?

Comment: Barely. Now it's clear that you're only interested in applications found in `shell:AppsFolder`. But what do AUMIDs have to do with anything? Your function doesn't use them, and it works for me (both pin and unpin, for "Microsoft Edge", "Skype", "Maps" and "Mail"). Maybe your computer is broken?

Comment: @conio If you want to know what apps are pinned to your Start Menu you might go ahead and export the Start Menu Layout xml. Here you will see an entry shown in the question that gives an AUMID of the pinned item. I want to pin my pinned shortcuts from one computer to another computer. Yes your correct my function does not accept AUMIDs but I want it to. Or turn AUMIDs into "these names" it does use. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: It gives such an entry only for Store apps. For desktop apps you get another entry which doesn't necessarily has an AUMID.

Comment: @conio Yes this is true. Good news is I figured that part out. I am only stuck on this specific issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* you want to find a Store/UWP application in the `shell:AppsFolder` by it's AUMID filter by the `Path` attribute instead of by the name. For Store apps the `Path` attribute contains the app's AUMID.

Note that for desktop apps the `Path` attribute gives an actual path to the executable.

Instead of trying to find the application name from the AUMID simply add them by their AUMID.

Jeez:

```
function Pin-App {    param(
        [string]$aumid,
        [switch]$unpin
    )
    try{
        if ($unpin.IsPresent){
            ((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | ?{$_.Path -eq $aumid}).Verbs() | ?{$_.Name.replace('&','') -match 'Unpin from Start'} | %{$_.DoIt()}
            return "App '$aumid' unpinned from Start"
        }else{
            ((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | ?{$_.Path -eq $aumid}).Verbs() | ?{$_.Name.replace('&','') -match 'Pin to Start'} | %{$_.DoIt()}
            return "App '$aumid' pinned to Start"
        }
    }catch{
        Write-Error "Error Pinning/Unpinning App! (App-Name correct?)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is not a Path attribute in the given xml only an AUMID

Comment: @nlstack01: But there is a `Path` attribute in the objects returned by the `Items()` method!