# How to find out whether a string is an AUMID for an installed UWP app?

Tags: c#, uwp

Is there a .Net library to use to test whether a string is an AUMID for an installed UWP app or not?

An example, if the user enters

```
Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge
```

How can I make sure that there actually is a UWP app with this AUMID installed?

Comment: Didn't we cover this in the comments to [your question three weeks ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45556089/convert-aumid-to-application-name-c-sharp)? An AUMID is just a string. If you want to know whether a string is an AUMID ***for an installed Windows Store app*** ask that.

Comment: @conio that is what I was asking. I updated the question. How to test a string is valid windows store app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the AUMID for a UWP has the format *FamilyName!AppID*, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/automate-launching-uwp-apps#launch-activation), for example.

To find out whether a given string is an AUMID for an installed UWP app you have to compare against that. You can build a list of all UWP app AUMIDs and see if the string is one of them, or you can split your string at the exclamation mark, find a package with the given family name, and if the package exists see if it has an application with the given application ID.

The API that does these things is the [`Windows.Management.Deployment.PackageManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Management.Deployment.PackageManager) class. Unfortunately, when enumerating the application inside a package, we don't get the application ID. Only in version 10.0.16257.0 of the SDK the [`Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.AppListEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.core.applistentry) class has an `AppUserModelId` property. Without it seems like you have to look at the package manifest yourself.

It's a lot easier to in PowerShell of course, since it has a cmdlet that get you the package manifest in object form. Microsoft has this example to generate all UWP app AUMIDs:

```
$installedapps = get-AppxPackage

$aumidList = @()
foreach ($app in $installedapps)
{
    foreach ($id in (Get-AppxPackageManifest $app).package.applications.application.id)
    {
        $aumidList += $app.packagefamilyname + "!" + $id
    }
}

$aumidList
```

(From: [Find the Application User Model ID of an installed app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/find-the-application-user-model-id-of-an-installed-app)
)

Now just see if your string is in the list.